# igraph Components: Which Algorithm (citation)?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, cran

I'm using igraph in academic research and I need to provide a proper citation for the algorithm used in the components() command. This algorithm returns the connected components of the graph. [The command in question is documented here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/components.html). It's part of the R/CRAN igraph library.

I think the algorithm used is the one below, which seems to be the canonical workhourse algoirthm [cited on the Wikipedia page for connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Hopcroft, J.; Tarjan, R. (1973), "[Algorithm 447: efficient algorithms for graph manipulation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/362248.362272)", Communications of the ACM, 16 (6): 372–378, doi:10.1145/362248.362272

Does anyone know what algorithm is used?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noticed that, `igraph` in R is actually written in `c/c++`. If you want to dig into the the details about how `components` is implemented, you should trace back to its `c` or `c++` source code.

Here is a link to the source code for `components`
https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/f9b6ace881c3c0ba46956f6665043e43b95fa196/src/components.c

However, it seems the algorithm applied is not mentioned in the source code. I guess you can reach the author by email and ask for help.